# Using AWK for best match replace

Tags: awk, replace

I have two files:
operators.txt     # includes Country_code and Country_name
49 Germany
43 Austria
32 Belgium
33 France

traffic.txt     # MSISDN and VLR_address (includes Country_code prefix)
123456789 491234567
123456788 432569874
123456787 333256987
123456789 431238523

I need to replace the VLR_address in traffic.txt file with Country_name from the first file.

The following awk command do that:
`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1,a[$2]}' <(cat operators.txt) <(cat traffic.txt|awk '{print $1,substr($2,1,2)}')`
123456789 Germany
123456788 Austria
123456787 France
123456789 Austria

but how to do it in case operators file is:
49 Germany
43 Austria
32 Belgium
33 France
**355 Albania**
**1246 Barbados**
**1 USA**

when country_code is not fixed length and in some case best match will apply e.g.
124612345 shall be Barbados
122018523 shall be USA

Comment: If the value `1246789` appeared in traffic.txt, how would we be able to tell whether the "Country_code prefix" is `1246` (Barbados) or `1` (USA)? You mentioned `best match will apply` but it's not clear what the definition of `best match` is.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a sample traffic.txt input and the associated output using the problematic country codes you mention later in your question. We need you to provide input/output files we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with to get a clear pass/fail result.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to try a substring of the correct length.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}
    { for (prefix in a) {
        p = a[prefix]; l = length(p)
        if ($2 ~ "^" p) { $2 = prefix; break } } }1' operators.txt traffic.txt
```

Notice how Awk itself is perfectly capable of reading files without the help of `cat`.  You also nearly never need to pipe one Awk script into another; just refactor to put all the logic in one script.

I swapped the value of the key and the value in the NR==FNR block but that is more of a stylistic change.

And, as always, the final `1` is a shorthand idiom for printing all lines.

Perhaps as an optimization, pull the prefixes into a regular expression so that you can simply match on them all in one go, instead of looping over them.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; regex = regex "|" $1; next}
    FNR == 1 { regex = "^(" substr(regex, 2) ")" } # trim first "|"
    match($2, regex) { $2 = a[substr($2, 1, RLENGTH)] } 1' operators.txt traffic.txt
```

The use of `match()` to pull out the length of the matched substring is arguably a complication; I wish Awk would provide this information for a normal regex match without the use of a separate dedicated function.

Comment: Regarding `I wish...` - but then a normal regexp match would be slower than today as it'd have to always populate equivalents of RSTART, RLENGTH, and possibly an array of capture groups (to mirror the 3rd arg for match() in GNU awk) when you usually don't need any of that. Today you have the choice of speed vs captured info.

Comment: Yeah, it's a reasonable and understandable compromise, I just find the implementation to be hideously clunky.

Comment: The OP hasn't provide input/output we can really test with yet but I THINK what you have wouldn't work as it's not testing the prefixes in longest-first order so, for example, it may not match `1246 Barbados` against `123456789 124612345` if it just happens to try `1 USA` first. You also don't seem to be using `l = length(p)` in that first script.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the 1-based `substr`. Not in a place where I can work on the more fundamental problem just now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The sample input/output you provided isn't adequate to test with as it doesn't include the cases you later described as problematic but if we modify it to include a representation of those later statements:

```
$ head operators.txt traffic.txt
==> operators.txt <==
49 Germany
43 Austria
32 Belgium
33 France
1 USA
355 Albania
1246 Barbados

==> traffic.txt <==
123456789 491234567
123456788 432569874
123456787 333256987
123456789 431238523
foo 124612345
bar 122018523
```

then this may be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    NR==FNR {
        keys[++numKeys] = $1
        map[$1] = $2
        next
    }
    {
        for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
            key = keys[keyNr]
            if ( index($2,key) == 1 ) {
                $2 = map[key]
                break
            }
        }
        print
    }
' <(sort -k1,1rn operators.txt) traffic.txt
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
123456789 Germany
123456788 Austria
123456787 France
123456789 Austria
foo Barbados
bar USA
```